# MongoDB Aggregation: How to group in array value?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

For example, Documents.

```
[
  {
    "username": "joy",
    "size_info": [
      {
        "size": "M",
        "width": 100,
        "height": 102
      },
      {
        "size": "M",
        "width": 102,
        "height": 104
      },
      {
        "size": "S",
        "width": 80,
        "height": 82
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to group `size_info.size` and push the array with the width and height.

I am trying to create an aggregation query.
For example for the given documents above, it would look like below:

```
[
  {
    "username": "joy",
    "size_info": [
      {
        "size": "M",
        "actual_size": [
          {
            "width": 100,
            "height": 102
          },
          {
            "width": 102,
            "height": 104
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "size": "S",
        "actual_size": [
          {
            "width": 80,
            "height": 82
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Is it possible?
Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `$unwind` - Deconstruct `size_info` array into multiple documents.
2. `$group` - Group by `username` and `size_info.size`. Add the documents into `actual_size` array.
3. `$group` - Group by `username`. Add the documents into `size_info` array.
4. `$project` - Decorate the output documents.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$size_info"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        username: "$username",
        size: "$size_info.size"
      },
      actual_size: {
        $push: {
          width: "$size_info.width",
          height: "$size_info.height"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id.username",
      size_info: {
        $push: {
          size: "$_id.size",
          actual_size: "$actual_size"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      username: "$_id",
      size_info: 1
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/l_YlJ1YcjqR)